# Are there websites to manage home improvement projects?

Tags: new-home

Are there any websites where you can create an account to manage your home with things such as:

- Layout or floor planning
- Budgets, project logging
- Wiring plans

I'm aware of FloorPlanner.com and Google Sketchup, but those are rather specific and I'm hoping for a more complete site to consolidate my home information/plans.

Answer (score 1):

There are products that do that

[Chief Architect](http://www.chiefarchitect.com/) comes to mind, though its an install-on-your-PC program, it does all you ask.

I have its little brother [Home Designer](http://www.chiefarchitect.com/home-designer-DIY/), which lets you do the design, visualization and parts lists, and gives you an upgrade credit to CA if you need more power.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little market for this. I've looked as well and have found both floorplanner and sketchup somewhat tedious to use. I always resort to some chart paper and drawing floor plans to scale. Google Docs are your friend here. Most youtube videos aren't super helpful either as they have part-info.

I've seen a few great examples of this in Home Depot who have decent books for various projects. Look around and browse them. Alternative what I've found to be a great resource is second hand stores like GoodWill, Value Village etc. even 10-20 year old home improvement books have great info.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visio is great for this and lays out its grids to whatever measurement you choose - for example each square can be 6 inches.

Also they have a ton of built in things that allow you to add lighting, doors, electrical, plumbing, code comments.  You can download even more for free or super cheap.  I have done a few floorplans and have used several products.  Visio works the best as long as it is 2D.